# How to draw elliptical gradient in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-graphics

Is it possible to get this kind of gradient in cocoa ? 
[image]

I can use simple `CGContextDrawRadialGradient` with clip made by `CGContextAddEllipseInRect` but the effect will slightly different.

Is it any posibility to draw exact this shade/gradient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a radial gradient, and then apply a scale trasnformation such that the y coordinate is squiched, and the x remains.

There is an advanced topic where you can define your own gradients providing an callback that calculates the color or so. Ist stated in Core Graphics docu.

Comment: I thought about that, probably the density of black 'pigment' will be stronger on Y axis. Definitely worth to try.